# SQL show all values with COUNT in a "WHERE IN ()" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select postal_code, count(postal_code) as c
from postal_codes
where postal_code in ('A0A 0A1', 'A0A 0A2', 'A0A 0A3', 'A0A 0A4', 'A0A 0B1', 'A0A 1B1', 'A0A 1B2')
group by postal_code
```

The last two values do not exist in the database ('A0A 1B1', 'A0A 1B2'), so they will not get displayed. I want them to be displayed, with a COUNT() value of 0.

The query will show me only the first 5 with a count of 1, but I need all 7, with the count of last two to be 0.

Is that possible?

Basically I have a list of values (with "WHERE IN()") that I need to check if they exist in the database.

Thank you!

Comment: See the answer by @yogesh below.  The basic idea is that if you have this requirement, then those postal code values should not just be hard-coded in a `WHERE` clause somewhere, they should be in a table.

Comment: What is the source of your list of target postal codes. As mentioned in the answer by @Yogesh Sharma you need to do a left join either through the value construct or preferably from a separate table.

Comment: That's true, I should create a temporary table with the values, since they can be 3000 in the list, which is a looong string to compute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` construct & do the `LEFT JOIN` :

```
select t.postal_code, count(p.postal_code) as c
from ( values ('A0A 0A1'), ('A0A 0A2'), ('A0A 0A3'), ('A0A 0A4'), ('A0A 0B1'), ('A0A 1B1'), ('A0A 1B2') 
     ) t(postal_code) left join
     postal_codes p
     on p.postal_code = t.postal_code
group by t.postal_code;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. . . Glad to hear from you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yogesh!